# Overlay video on video in MoviePy

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I am using python MoviePy library to overlay video with transparent background in .mov format on video in .mp4. Here is the code I have so far.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip
zm_video_path = "1.mov"


def add_zm(fg_in_bg_avi):
    clip1 = VideoFileClip(fg_in_bg_avi)
    clip3 = VideoFileClip(zm_video_path, has_mask=True)
    video = CompositeVideoClip([clip1, clip3])
    name = 'New_video'
    video.write_videofile(name, audio=False)  # No audio first
    video.close()
    return name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_have_zm = add_zm("background.mp4")
```

This code worked when I was overlaying a GIF on the same video. I see the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 1806: invalid continuation byte

Thanks in advance. Maybe you know how to do it on ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output_path="output.mp4"

video_clip = VideoFileClip((video_view), target_resolution=(1080, 1920)) #b .mp4 file

overlay_clip = VideoFileClip((animeeer), has_mask=True, target_resolution=(1080, 1920)) #.mov file with alpha channel


final_video = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video_clip, overlay_clip])  


final_video.write_videofile(
    output_path,
    fps=30,
    remove_temp=True,
    codec="libx264",
    audio_codec="aac",
    threads = 6,
)
```